# z-index of parent greater than child

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have 3 divs: `#parent`, `child`, `second`

I want the `#parent` div to be on top of `#child` div and `#child` div to be on top on `#second` div. 
How can I set the `z-index` or configure the divs to achieve this?
Right now, the `#child` div is on top of both.
I prefer not to change the HTML code and simply fix it with CSS.

I've checked other similar questions but none have been able to provide a solution to the problem I'm facing.

```css
#parent, #child, #second{
    height: 50px;
}
#parent{
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 500px;
}
#child{
    background-color: #216583;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 400px;
}
#second{
    background-color: #f76262;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, velit!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

Comment: @ObsidianAge That is the exact opposite of what I'm asking. I want the parent z-index to be greater than the child and show on top of it.

Comment: remove z-index from parent then make the child -1 and the second div -2

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh that worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @TemaniAfif do you have any explanation why removing the `z-index` works while setting it to `0` (default value) doesn't work

Comment: @TemaniAfif I was just about to ask you that

Comment: @Dadboz read the duplicate link, I am adding a detailed explanation there.

Comment: @Dadboz and the default value is not `0` it's `auto` and here is a big difference

Comment: @TemaniAfif Okay, so that initially fixed the issue but now I cant select from child layer. The text is unselectable and any link I place in that div won't click.

Comment: add `position:relative;z-index:0` to body element and read about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events